# How to deal with Django Cascade deleted objects in django-simple-history?

Tags: python, django, history, cascade, django-simple-history

I have a problem with *django-simple-history* when I use cascade deletion on objects.

I have several tables in my database that inherit from other tables, so I’ve set the deletion to cascade.
The problem is that when I want to query Historical Objects generated by django-simple-history, I do have the one in the parent table, but for objects in the children table, that were automatically deleted by Django, I have this error :

```
MyApp.models.parentTable_object.DoesNotExist: parentTable_object matching query does not exist.
```

If I understand the problem, *django-simple-history* tried to create a Historical object for my deleted object but failed because it needed the parent object it inherited and that no longer exists at this point.

I can’t do without cascading so I hope it’s possible because *django-simple-history* has met all my expectations so far.

Thanks you for your help

My environment:

- OS: Windows 10
- Browser: Firefox
- Django Simple History Version: 3.1.1
- Django Version: 4.0.3
- Database Version: django's integrated SqLite3

Comment: I think you should create an issue on the repository with all the details on how to reproduce the bug: https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues

Comment: @ruddra Already done but no response for almost a year :/

Answer (score 0):

Let's see if I understand the problem correctly, this would be an example data model:

```
class Parent(models.Model):  
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    history = HistoricalRecords()

class Child(models.Model):`
    parent = HistoryForeignKey(Parent, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    history = HistoricalRecords()
```

Please note the `HistoricForeignKey` [link](https://django-simple-history.readthedocs.io/en/latest/querying_history.html#historicforeignkey).

When you do delete a Parent instance, you cannot get the child object anymore.

You probably get the `DoesNotExist` issue when trying to fetch the children like:

`Child.history.as_of(time_stamp).get(parent=parent)`

If you try to get the Child with the parent ID like:

`Child.history.as_of(time_stamp).get(parent_id=parent_id)`

In that way you can still get the child through the HistoricalChild table.

Also notice [this](https://github.com/jazzband/django-simple-history/issues/880) thread on github get a more clear idea.

In one of the messages this person mentions the issue you are having as well

> This also has a benefit of allowing you to know if an instance is derived from history or not, which might be useful as well. I noticed this does not work for chained lookups however, for example if you have a get_object_or_404 that uses a filter like b__c__id it doesn't seem to see "b" in this case. I'm sure with another patch that could be made to work as well.

Up until now this patch has not yet been made.

I hope this helps you, if not, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer.
Actually i do use the `HistoricForeignKey` but i'm not trying to access to the history objects by the `Child.history.as_of(time_stamp).get(parent=parent)` but directly by the Historical Model that is supposed to save all changes of the original Model. And so the historic object of the Child object is raising an error because it was created after the parent object was deleted. And so it's foreignKey attribute links on nothing. 
Well , thats how i understand it.